# Linq query to find matches in nested lists

Tags: linq

Using the classes below I need to select items from AllMeta where there is a match in Meta.

The match criteria is that at least 1 group in Meta.Groups.Name matches that of AllMeta.Values.Groups.Name.

```
AllMeta: is a dictionary<string, WikiMeta>
Meta: is a WikiMeta

public class WikiMeta
{
    public string ContentTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageMetaDescription { get; set; }
    public List<WikiArticle> Articles = new List<WikiArticle>();
    public List<WikiGroup> Groups = new List<WikiGroup>();
}

public class WikiGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested `Any` is the direct approach:

```
var result = AllMeta
    .Where(kv => 
        Meta.Any(m => 
            m.Groups.Any(mg => 
                kv.Value.Groups.Any(vmg => 
                    vmg.Name == mg.Name))));
```

> Apologies Tim, slight error in specification. Meta is a single
>   WikiMeta but with one or more Groups.

```
var result = AllMeta
  .Where(kv => Meta.Groups.Any(mg => kv.Value.Groups.Any(vmg =>  vmg.Name == mg.Name)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Tim - I'll test it out

Comment: Apologies Tim, slight error in specification. Meta is a single WikiMeta but with one or more Groups.